# Is there a NLog LayoutRender to get an web.config appSettings key?

Tags: logging, web-config, nlog, appsettings

Before I go off and create my own, I'd like to know if there is an NLog layout renderer that exists to log an appSettings key/value from web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW,

Here is a nearly identical question that has an answer with a LayourRenderer implementation that might do what you want.

[NLog config file to get configuration setting values from a web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107499/nlog-config-file-to-get-configuration-setting-values-from-a-web-config)