# NLog config file to get configuration setting values from a web.config

Tags: web-config, nlog, appsettings

Is there a method to get a value from the `<ApplicationSettings>` section of a web.config within NLog layout variables?

I already store SMTP details within my web.config and don't want to duplicate the settings just to use within my NLog.config.

Ideally I'd like to do something like: `${aspnet-config:SmtpHostServer}`
which then fetches the value from the web.config

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I couldn't see any obvious way to do this other than creating my own `LayoutRenderer` (see below). If you're putting into your own assembly don't forget to add the following into your NLog.Config:

```xml
<extensions>
   <add assembly="YOURASSEMBLYNAMEHERE" />
</extensions>
```

Hope this helps someone else:

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("aspnet-config")]
public class AspNetConfigValueLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    [DefaultParameter]
    public string Variable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        if (this.Variable == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        builder.Append(Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[this.Variable], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 13):

**Updated Answer**

NLog ver. 4.6 includes `${appsetting:SmtpHostServer}` in the core NLog-nuget-package. No longer requires NLog.Extended. See also https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer

NLog.Extensions.Logging ver. 1.4 includes `${configsetting}` that allows one to read settings from appsettings.json. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

**Original Answer**

Nowadays this is possible without custom code:

Use [NLog.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extended/) and use 
`${appsetting:SmtpHostServer}`.

See [docs for ${appsetting}](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer)

Please note: this isn't supported in .NET Core / .NET standard yet.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Julian - useful to know. I've since changed logging providers.